# change default shell sh uses for jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

the "sh" step default to cmd on windows and bash on linux.

How can I make sh step default to powershell on windows?

PS has a lot of bash alias so I could potentially use "sh" on both platforms with the same commands if "sh" defaulted to powershell on windows agents

Answer (score 1):

For *nix hosted Jenkins it is in following way:

```
sh "#!/bin/zsh\n pwd; ls"
```

*NOTE:* be aware that the shell must be existing in system

for windows though, it is not that streight forward, and cause there is no posibility (or at least I do not know about it) to switch to PS from CMD via command, you have to make sure your windows system default Command Promt is set to Powershell. I think you can do it from Control Panel, but neverthless, there is a way to that for sure.

Comment: OP is asking how to change the _default_ shell. This solution only works for the single `sh` call. If you want to use this implementation for more than a one-off, you need to preface the argument to every one of your `sh` calls with `#!/bin/zsh`.